# Which image filter acts like "surface tension"?

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for an image filter that does the following operation:

In my first image, I have two spheres. After applying the filter, I'd like to have them "glued together" which something that kind of resembles surface tension.

Remarks:

- The image will be 2D/3D, with the signed distance to the surface of the spheres encoded as grayscale.
- It would be great if it is something that's already in Numpy / Scipy.
- I know that people do similiar stuff on meshes, but I'd like to have it as an image filter.

**Example images (sorry for the different formats):**

[image]
[image: Image 2 - after filtering]

Comment: *morphological dilation* might appeal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Morphological Closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)).

A morphological closing is a combination of dilation followed by erosion; typical image processing operations available in *most* image processing libraries.

SciPy has a "simple" [binary closing method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_closing.html) which does this on binary images. By experimenting with different *structuring elements* you can close smaller or bigger gaps.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could use a Gaussian Filter.

The following Python code does something similar to what you show in your images.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter, laplace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, x = np.mgrid[-2:2:101j, -2:2:101j]
z = np.maximum(0, 0.2 - (x + 0.5)**2 - y**2) +\
    np.maximum(0, 0.2 - (x - 0.5)**2 - y**2)
z2 = gaussian_filter(z, sigma=7)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.contourf(x, y, z)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.contourf(x, y, z2)
plt.savefig("gaussian_filter.png")
```

The results is the following

[image]

The caveat is the selection of `sigma`. That parameter would determine how spread is the Gaussian filter.

Comment: It does agglomerate the nearby bodies, but it does look more like a diffusion than a surface tension phenomena. Surface tension would in a way "conserve the volume" of the original spheres while maintaining a sharp interface. Still a good starting point.

Comment: @BlaB, that's true, but to generate a new surface you would need to move material from one side to the other.